# How to read floats onto a list from a file?

Tags: python, list, file, while-loop

I am asked to create a program that will read amounts (expenses) into a list. After they have been read into a list, calculate and print:

- total dollar amt
- how many receipts in the file
- average
- max amt
- listing of the receipts from smallest to largest.

I have a rough draft of the code, but the way I have written the program I have a limited number of receipts that the program stores. The total amt, average, and max amount are easy to figure, as you will see in the code. My problem is reading the expenses into a list and figuring out how many receipts would be appropriate since I am supposed to have any number of them.
If I have to delete all of my code and start from scratch, then that is what I will have to do. Everything I have done in this program I comprehend. I feel like I am not seeing the bigger picture of what I am supposed to be doing.

I have some code commented out because I would rather focus on getting the proper code before I create a file and write information onto the file.

```
def main():
    #expense_file = open("expenses.txt", "w")
    total1 = 0
    receipt1 = []
    enter_expense = float(input("Enter expense: $"))
    while enter_expense > 0:
        receipt1.append(format(enter_expense, ".2f"))
        total1 += enter_expense
        enter_expense = float(input("Enter expense: $"))
    #expense_file.write(str(receipt1))
    print("Your total for receipt #1 is: $", format(total1, ".2f"), "\n" +
          "Receipt #1: ", receipt1)


    total2 = 0
    receipt2 = []
    enter_expense = float(input("Enter expense: $"))
    while enter_expense > 0:
        receipt2.append(format(enter_expense, ".2f"))
        total2 += enter_expense
        enter_expense = float(input("Enter expense: $"))
    #expense_file.write(str(receipt2))
    print("Your total for receipt #2 is: $", format(total2, ".2f"), "\n" +
          "Receipt #2: ", receipt2)


    total3 = 0
    receipt3 = []
    enter_expense = float(input("Enter expense: $"))
    while enter_expense > 0:
        receipt3.append(format(enter_expense, ".2f"))
        total3 += enter_expense
        enter_expense = float(input("Enter expense: $"))
    #expense_file.write(str(receipt3))
    print("Your total for receipt #3 is: $", format(total3, ".2f"), "\n" +
          "Receipt #3: ", receipt3)
    
    total_receipt = receipt1 + receipt2 + receipt3
    total = total1 + total2 + total3
    average = total / len(total_receipt)
    print("Total expense: $", total)
    print("Average expense: $", average)
    print("Minimum expense: $", min(total_receipt), "and maximum expense: $", max(total_receipt))
    total_receipt.sort()
    print("Sorted list of expenses: ", total_receipt)

#    expense_file.close()


main()
```

Comment: Put the receipts into a list.  Don't repeat code like that -- use a loop.

Comment: If you have to read floats from a file, why are you prompting and reading on the Terminal?